# Need help creating a try and catch in python to validate data type and range

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to create a python football manager program that asks users a players name and the asks how many goals the player has scored. The goals scored cannot be a negative number or more than 6. I'm also trying to get the code to validate that goals scored is an integer and not a string. Here's the best I could do:

```
goals = ""
while goals == "":
    try:
        goals = int(input("Enter goals scored"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer")
```

How can I get the code to also check the range? Doing:

```
while goals == "" and goals not in range(0,6):
    #Try catch loop
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using `try...except ValueError`, why are you also using `while goals == ""`? If user didn't enter anything, `int()` will raise `ValueError`. So you can change your code to `while goals not in range(0,6):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `or`, not an `and`.

If the input isn't an int, you'll get a `ValueError`, and `goals` will remain `""`. If you don't get a `ValueError` a valid int is assigned to `goals`, so you need to check the range:

```
while goals == ""  or goals not in range(0,6):
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem lies with you assigning a string as the default to a variable that is truly integer-based. You say that `goals` cannot be negative or greater than 6, then use an invalid integer as your original value for `goals`.

```
goals = -1

while not 0 <= goals <= 6:
    text = input('Enter goals scored (between 0 and 6 inclusive): ')

    try:
        goals = int(text)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an actual integer.')
```